# Why do Canadians have hinged heads?

Tags: animation, south-park

In *South Park*, Canadians are animated with less detailed features and heads that are cut into two different pieces, with the top part bobbing when they talk. The characters can tell the difference, as in the episode *Christmas in Canada* where Kyle's dad replies "Yeah, I can tell" (or something very similar) when Ike's parents come to claim him and say that they are Canadian. Is there a reason, or just for the funny? Subpoint: Why do Canadians have the weird heads, as opposed to making fun of any other nation?

Comment: We make fun of Canadians because they're a closer target than the French.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the South Park Studios [interview with Matt Stone](https://web.archive.org/web/20120523235112/http://www.spscriptorium.com/SPMedia/MattStoneInterview-04052005.htm) (where users were encouraged to ask questions):

> **j0l0n: from Henbob** -> What made you think of the canadians having
> those funny head and everything is square? its brilliant! cheers
> **MattStone:** Well the idea came to us during a trip to Toronto. That's
> just the way they all look up there...

In a [different interview](https://web.archive.org/web/20120305203641/http://www.spscriptorium.com/SPinfo/TwentyQuestions.htm) with the same site, this was recorded:

> **Taison:** Ghislain Deslierres asks, I want to know why all the Canadians
> in South Park have such weird heads because I'm a Canadian and I'm
> sure that a lot of Canadian South Park fans would also want to know
> why we must have those faces? So, what's the deal with the flapping
> heads and beady eyes?
>
> **Trey**. Go look in the mirror.
> **Matt**: Yeh.
> [Trey
> goes into fits of laughter]
> That's what, that's what you, that's what
> you look like to us. Everything started because Terrance and Phillip
> were characters first, and they weren't necessarily Canadian. And were
> later on we were like, "They're Canadian."
> **Trey**: But the idea with
> Terrance and Phillip was, even worse animation than… South Park.
> **Matt**:
> Yeh.
> **Trey**: Because, t-Terrance and Phillip was our answer to- When the
> show first came out, and everyone was saying, "South Park is horrible
> animation, and is nothing but fart jokes." And we're like, "Nononono.
> Here's horrible animation and nothing but fart jokes," right? And
> that's what Terrance and Phillip was, it was our answer to that. And
> then it sort of grew and and, and, at that time we thought Terrance
> and Phillip were probably like, British or something, and then they
> just became Canadian out of necessity.
> **Matt**: And some grief for the…
> **Trey**: Yeah, and then we decided that all Canadians look like that, and
> that was sweet, because-
> **Matt**: We, we loved the idea that… that,
> different characters in South Park don't… look any different. Race.
> Race doesn't matter.
> **Taison**: M-hm.
> **Matt**: Only nationality. So, like, a
> black… American… es- essentially looks the same as a white American,
> but just… different skin color.
> **Taison**: M-hm.
> **Matt**: But, um, but a
> black Canadian looks like a white Canadian,
> [Trey laughs]
> and uh he
> looks totally different.
> **Trey**: Yeah.
> **Taison**: Yeah. Okay.
> **Matt**: And
> like, a Chinese-American looks like everybody else in South Park, with
> different skin tone. The Chinese Chinese… looks like, a different, a
> different thing.
> **Taison**: Yeah.

So there's a few reasons, but clearly comedic effect was the largest!

Comment: Great answer! It also clears up my follow-up question, which is why Mongolians look entirely different than Chinese people. Nationality is king. Got it.